# Mapping attributes from input shapefile to output CAD file using FME?

Tags: fme-form, dwg

I'm trying to do a simple data conversion using FME where I take a point shapefile and convert it to CAD (DWG).

[image]

Even though I have connected the attributes I want mapped into the output file, the resulting CAD files ends up with no attributes. If I use 'Extended Entity Data' as my Attribute Output parameter I get several attributes but not these 3 three user attributes. I'm new to FME. My input data has a Z value attribute but is not actually Z- Aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [CoordinatorExtractor](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/coordinateextractor.htm) and a [3DForcer](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/3dforcer.htm?Highlight=3DForcer) to preserve the coordinates as 3D.

In the 3DForcer preserver your existing z values.

Note: you may have to expose those DWG/CAD values before you use these two transformers.

[image]

From Attributes

[image]